# Trouble attempting nested sort

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset with three fields: region, product, sales. I would like to display by-region bar charts of sales by product, with bars sorted within each region. I follow the recipe on

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/nestedsorting

until I get to Step 4, at which point Tableau (9.2) shows me this.

[image: tableau bug]

What went wrong? And how do I get my nested sort?

Answer (score 0):

... turns out I can do the desired sort this way.

[image: tableau bug2]